# Calculate row-wise or column-wise means using R terra functions

Tags: r, raster, terra

I'm trying to calculate row or column means of a SpatRaster/SpatRaster stack using the R terra package in order to make a Hovmoller plot, but am finding myself stumped.

I'd typically just use something like this:

```
# Test matrix

A = matrix(seq(1,6,1),4,3,byrow = TRUE)

# Usually lots of NAs in the data

A[c(2,4,5)] <- NA

# Calculate the mean of each row

m = apply(A, 1, "mean", na.rm =T)
```

How would someone calculate this using terra functions? Reading the documentation for the various app() functions it doesn't seem apparent how to calculate values based on SpatRaster dimensions. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You don't want to get the average by row or col as a separate variable like what you've shown for matrices. You want a spatial mean (or rather you want your mean values to be in regards to the spatial variables), and as @Chris mentioned, there are specific functions for that purpose.

Comment: Perhaps [rasterVis](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rasterVis/html/hovmoller-methods.html) pkg, that uses terra in example?, or likely closer to your datasets, [Hovmoller Penn State R meteo](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/meteo820/node/658).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate`

This

```
x <- rast(A)
aggregate(x, c(1, ncol(x)), mean, na.rm=TRUE) |> values()
#     lyr.1
#[1,]   2.0
#[2,]   5.5
#[3,]   2.0
#[4,]   5.5
```

Returns the same numbers as

```
apply(A, 1, "mean", na.rm =T)
#[1] 2.0 5.5 2.0 5.5
```